# Is it possible to use IRC Chat on new Empathy?

Tags: 14.04, empathy, irc

I can't find any option to add IRC acount on the Online Accounts service.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install the irc plugin `account-plugin-irc`

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-irc
```

After that you should be able to use empathy as irc client but beware empathy has a very limited function as an IRC cliente. I would recomend to use a dedicated IRC client.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat#IRC_Clients

Comment: for newer versions (I have 17.10 but it's probably the same for older versions too) you need instead this package `telepathy-idle` ([source](https://help.gnome.org/users/empathy/stable/irc-manage))