# Using IRC with password on empathy gets stuck on "Authorize Ubuntu"

Tags: 14.04, password, empathy, online-accounts, irc

I'm trying to set up empathy to use IRC on the Rizon network. After following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463033/is-it-possible-to-use-irc-chat-on-new-empathy) instructions to add IRC support, adding the Rizon server to the list (using SSL), accepting the self-signed certificates and adding my username and password in the options, I get a notification reading

"**Applications can no longer access your MY_USERNAME_HERE on Rizon Online Account**
Choose Online Accounts from the user menu to reinstate access to this account
"

Unfortunately, pressing Grant Access on the Online Accounts page will not do anything except take me back to my account settings. The only way to make it work is to delete my password.

Comment: Unfortunately Emphaty is not the greatest IRC client. I would consider using a dedicated client like Hexchat or Irsii, or if you preffer the "gnome irc client" Polari.

Comment: Oh right. I was hoping to use empathy due to its integration, but since using pidgin as a workaround I notices that pidgin too uses the messaging-indicator's status (available, busy etc..).  Also, since I assume that there is no real way to fix this, what do I do with this question?